# oVirt qemu-kvm listening on wrong IP

Tags: kvm-virtualization, ipv6, qemu, ovirt

I'm new to oVirt but managed to configure it and take over the console on an IPv4 network, using VNC instead of spice. However, I've noticed that the qemu-kvm process only binds to the IPv4 interface and not on the IPv6 interface.

So far I haven't found where to configure on which interfaces qemu-kvm listens when controlled by oVirt. In the very near future, my only option will be to access the oVirt engine via IPv6 (eventhough the oVirt engine will continue to run dual-stack)

Anyone has experience with changing these settings?

Answer (score 0):

https://ovirt.org/develop/release-management/features/network/ipv6-support/

Looks like full IPv6 support is still missing. You can set the VMs up with IPv6 inside the guest OS, that will work